# How to fix cucumber's class step definition problem causing high CPU usage when using Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, cucumber, gherkin

When opening any class containing many steps (given, when, and then), the methods execute the steps in the feature file; at this time, the CPU will increase (80–90%). It makes the computer very laggy.
Only when closing that class will the CPU return to normal.

When I turn off the cucumber plugin so it can't search for that step, I don't see the CPU increase. I'm thinking about the cause but haven't found a way to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

After many days of research, I noticed that every time I open these classes, it takes a certain amount of time for each method to display "usages". I think this is the reason why cpu increases.

Usages is a feature of Intellij, it will tell us where this method is being used and count them. The more the method is used in the project, the slower this part is displayed.

Therefore, I turned this feature off. It's located in **Settings > Editor > Inlay Hints > Code vision > Usages**. (Windows) We just need to **uncheck** it.
Our CPU will no longer increase every time we open that class.
[image]

Comment: To understand why exactly the IDE consumes so much CPU for showing Inlay Hints please record a CPU snapshot as per https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241235 and contact JetBrains support team at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new